# Partial Sum of Binary Sequence not Working

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have the following code:

```
G[0] := RandomInteger[];
Do[
 If[
  RandomReal[] < 0.3,
  G[i] = 1,
  G[i] = 0
  ],
 {i, 1, 50}]
Table[Sum[G[j], {j, 0, i}], {i, 0, 50}]
```

The first entry of G is either 0 or 1. The following entries of G have a probability 0.3 of being a 1. This generates a sequence that looks right. However, on the last line where I ask it to give me a table with partial sums, it doesn't do it. What could be wrong?

Comment: Why not use `RandomChoice[]` instead?

Comment: As J.M. said, `RandomInteger[] + Accumulate@RandomChoice[{0.3, 0.7} -> {1, 0}, 50]` gives you partial sums for a binary list generated according to your weights.

Comment: For this example I simplified the probability to 0.3 for the purposes of asking the question. In what I am actually working on the probability comes from a function calculated at every stage. Would RandomChoice[] work with a function inside?

Comment: Consider editing your question with an example that more closely resembles your actual problem, then (if not the problem itself).